# Flurry setAge and Gender

Tags: swift, flurry

So I am trying to follow Flurry.com rules about sending Age and Gender before you start the flurry.

```
        switch UserSettings().gender {
            case "Male":
                Flurry.setGender("m")
            case "Female":
                Flurry.setGender("f")
            default:
            break;
        }
        
       
        let ageComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year],
                                                from: UserSettings().dateofbirth,
                                                to: Date())
        let age = Int32(ageComponents.year!)
        Flurry.setAge(age);
        Flurry.startSession("XXXXXXXXXXX", with: FlurrySessionBuilder
              .init()
              .withCrashReporting(true)
              .withLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelAll))
        return true
    }
```

However while I can see it is sending it to Flurry.

```
2021-05-09 21:44:44.169277+0800 DRN1[1881:365938] -[FlurryStreamCoreBuffer streamMessage:]: msg = <FlurryStreamUserGender: 0x281ea80c0, type = 168, json = {   "fl.frame.version" : 1,   "fl.demo.gender" : 1 }>
```

I can't seem to see it in my dash board. I am wondering what I might be doing wrong.

[image: Flurry Desktop App]

Comment: Which dashboard are you checking with? Your code is correct, so this might be an issue of how long it takes the data to propagate(several hours at most), or there might be a problem.

Comment: @FlurryAnalyticsSupport I am looking at Audience  > Overview - please see screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is showing the dashboard that only has built in charts for estimated age and gender. The easiest way to check is to go to the "App Activity" dashboard, click on "Breakouts", and selected either Reported Age or Reported Gender.